# How can add annotation at the end of my route?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I calculate the route and I want to add a pin annotation at the end...

declare location, send request, declare directions and reset my map view with new directions...

```
guard let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    let request = createDirectionsRequest(from: location)
    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
    resetMapView(withNew: directions)
```

after I calculate the direction and add annotation...

```
directions.calculate { [unowned self] (response, error) in
        guard let response = response else { return }

        for route in response.routes {
            self.mapView.add(route.polyline, level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)
            self.mapView.setCenter(route.polyline.coordinate, animated: true)
            self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
            self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(route.polyline.coordinate, route.distance*0.75, route.distance*0.75), animated: true)

            let routeAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            routeAnnotation.coordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(route.polyline.points()[route.polyline.pointCount/2])
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(routeAnnotation)
        }
    }
```

and this is the result... the annotation is not in the right position of my route... where i'm wrong?

[image]

**UPDATE**

In my case I solved the problem... 
I select my destination with a pointer positioned on center of the view... move the map and return me the center coordinates with a function that i write for calculate it:

```
func getCenterLocation(for mapView: MKMapView) -> CLLocation {
    let latidude = mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude
    let longitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude

    return CLLocation(latitude: latidude, longitude: longitude)
}
```

I simply call this func for determine my pin coordinates that are the same of the center of the view (pointer) and consequently are the same the destination point...

```
routeAnnotation.coordinate = self.getCenterLocation(for: self.mapView).coordinate
```

and this is the result

[image]

more solutions are accepted...